# Request.Session not saving cookies

Tags: python, session, python-requests

Requests library not saving the session/cookies, further not able to make REST API calls.

I have tried

```
with requests.Session() as amp_session:  # type: Session
    url = "https://xyz.airwave.com/"
    login = amp_session.post(url, data=login_creds, verify=False)
    print("here are the cookies---------------->",amp_session.cookies)
```

Login status is 200 but I get the following output:

```
('here are the cookies---------------->', <RequestsCookieJar[]>)
```

How can I make sure the session object has the cookie so that I can make API calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should replace:

```
print("here are the cookies---------------->",amp_session.cookies)
```

with

```
print("here are the cookies---------------->",amp_session.cookies.get_dict())
```

hope this helps!

Comment: `here are the cookies----------------> {}` this is the output I got.

Comment: @MR.i this means that amp_session doesn’t have any cookies

Comment: is there a work-around to maintain session without cookies?

Comment: @MR.i are you just trying to login to the website?

Comment: Try to make api calls, to retrieve data